# Neural Networks: Is an epoch in SGD the same as an epoch in mini-batch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In SGD an epoch would be the full presentation of the training data, and then there would be N weight updates per epoch (if there are N data examples in the training set).

If we now do mini-batches instead, say in batches of 20. Does one epoch now consist of N/20 weight updates, or is an epoch 'lengthened' by 20 so that it contains the same number of weight updates?

I ask this as in a couple of papers learning seems to be too quick for the number of epochs stated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tradeoff batch size vs. number of iterations to train a neural network](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network)

Comment: The question is more on convention, i.e. if someone states they have trained a network for 10 epochs using mini-batches of 20, does this mean there has been 10*N weight updates, or 10*N/20?

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion, maybe http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164875/12359 answers your question?

Answer (score 9):

In the neural network terminology:

- one **epoch** = one forward pass and one backward pass of *all* the training examples
- **batch size** = the number of training examples in one forward/backward pass. The higher the batch size, the more memory space you'll need.
- number of **iterations** =  number of passes, each pass using [batch size] number of examples. To be clear, one pass = one forward pass + one backward pass (we do not count the forward pass and backward pass as two different passes).

Example: if you have 1000 training examples, and your batch size is 500, then it will take 2 iterations to complete 1 epoch.

Answer (score 2):

Franck's answer is completely correct. If you'd pay more attention to his message you'd realize you're stating the same thing as he is, just you're omitting one important aspect.

Firstly, an **epoch** does indeed refer to a complete **pass** (forward & backward) **of all the training examples**. This should not be a debatable topic.

Secondly, when using mini-batch gradient descent, the parameters are indeed **updated at each pass**. Franck and you, both stated the same thing, just differently. However, I believe your confusion originates from the fact that, when using mini-batch gradient descent (or stochastic gradient descent), multiple **iterations** are required to complete an epoch. Aspect clearly outlined by Franck.

For clarity, if there are *n* training samples, there are ***n*** / (**# of mini-batches**) **iterations** required for mini-batch GD to complete an epoch, ***n*** **iterations** for SGD, and evidently **1** for batch GD.

I believe that, in general, this is a confusing topic and it is important for others to have a clear understanding of the meaning of a batch, mini-batch, epoch, pass, and iteration. Thus, confusing messages like yours should be highlighted and corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Epoch is a word that means a single pass through a training set, **not all training examples.**

So, yes. If we do mini-batches GD instead of a batch GD, say in batches of 20, One epoch now consist of N/20 weight updates. N is the total number of samples.

To be verbose, In a batch gradient descent, a single pass through the training allows you to take only one gradient descent step. With mini-batch (batch size = 5,000) gradient descent, a single pass through the training set, that is one epoch, allows you to take 5,000 gradient descent steps.