# Experience replay, why store SARS' and not SAQRS'

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

For Q-learning Experience replay, why do we store into the bank observations:

> { stateFrom, actionIx, imediateReward, resultingState }

instead of

> { stateFrom, actionIx, **actionQValue**, imediateReward, resultingState }

The first choice seems to be preferred in all equations I see. [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250943/187816) [[2]](https://www.slideshare.net/EliasHasnat/reinforcement-learning-61282674)
But wouldn't it be good to already have $actionQValue$ at hand during backprop, so we don't have to spend time computing it again?

Or is there something fundimental, like we can't rely on such a actionQValue because it might become obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there something fundimental, like we can't rely on such a $actionQValue$ because it might become obsolete?

Exactly that. The estimates for Q values, and the preferred choice of next action, are changing as the learning progresses. Action value estimates in a control problem are *non-[stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)* as the agent improves its policy.

Experience replay is about re-using the observations from the environment - what reward R and resulting state S' occur when in state S, the agent takes action A.

You *could* code an agent to attempt to also re-use knowledge of its "previous self", such as what the action values were. However, this would be counter-productive, as the older estimates for Q will be biased towards initialisation values (typically all zero or random), and/or towards the action values of older policies that the agent has since improved upon.